# Remove javascript console sentences from source using gsub

Tags: javascript, ruby, debugging, console, trace

Im noob in ruby and i coding a simple rakefile ...

one of my task remove from javascript files the "console" lines, what do you thing about the current snippet?

```
def self.remove_debug()
  FileList[File.join(DIST_DIR, '**/console-nodebug.js')].each do |file_name|
    puts "file: #{file_name}"
    content = File.read(file_name).gsub(/console\..*?;/m, "// console removed")
    File.open(file_name, 'wb') { |file| file.write(content) }
  end
end
```

its fine?? i need to change something?

i test the code and all goes fine, but ... im looking for good practices ...

thks!

Comment: yup, i looking for opinions, good practices, ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a debug variable and have ruby initialize that variable (I really don't know much about ruby, I leave this to you, I guess something like injecting it in the html file). And then in you js file you may do like this:

```
if (debug) {
  console.log("I'm debugging! Yay!! XD");
}
```

In my humble opinion this is better than modifying the file.

Hope it helped, good luck!

==EDIT==

If it's a minified file that you need to shrink I would suggest replacing your regex bu "/* console removed */" instead of "// console removed", just in case that there is some more code after that line.

Other than that I think you will be ok. Is it working?

Comment: yup, im in that way ... but im working for a lazy javascript minified file to my productive environment ... debug traces === kb ... cos' im removing lines in the productive build phase ... thks !

Comment: only one thing ... if u forget in "console" statement the final ";", gsub destroy all code until found ";" character. But in my case i had a pre-task to perform jlint check over the code xD

Comment: Then maybe you should check for the closed ')' that is not quoted and matches the oppening ')' of the console... hehehe, maybe is too much work if you already check it with jslint ^.^, I'm glad it's working!